# Android, timePicker and his value when not being called

Tags: android, datetime, set, picker

My time picker work perfectly, but only in one case it make wrong output. If i call edit function and all variables are filled from database, and i dont call time picker (click on button with this function), it rewrite my db value with actual system value. How can i fix it ? After i click on button with picker, they show me my db value, textview from startactivity shown db value, but after save, it save db value only if i click on picker button (call him) ... how can i set value, then i musnt click on it and value stay from db

```
public class PredmetPridajActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
//DateFormat fmtTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
SimpleDateFormat fmtTime = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
SimpleDateFormat fmtDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm"); // upravit na den alebo v selecte lepsi order

TextView timeLabel;
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance ();

public static final String ODOSLI = "odosli";

private DatabaseOp mDbHelper;

String username;
String odosli = "";
String predmet;
String obsah;
String poloha;
String vyucujuci;
String hodina;
String den;

int item;
String strItem;

EditText tv_nazov;
EditText tv_poznamka;
EditText tv_miesto;
EditText tv_vyucujuci;

private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.predmet_pridaj);

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_dni);

    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.dni, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    mDbHelper = new DatabaseOp(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    timeLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
    updateLabel();

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    username = sharedPrefs.getString("prefUsername", "NULL");

    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.hasExtra(ODOSLI))
        odosli = i.getStringExtra(ODOSLI);

    if (odosli.length()>0)
    {
        dbOperations();

        tv_nazov = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.predmet);
        tv_nazov.setText(predmet);

        tv_poznamka = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obsah);
        tv_poznamka.setText(obsah);

        tv_miesto = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.miesto);
        tv_miesto.setText(poloha);

        tv_vyucujuci = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vyucujuci);
        tv_vyucujuci.setText(vyucujuci);

        timeLabel.setText(hodina);

        spinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(den));
    }
}

public void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    strItem = parent.getItemAtPosition (position).toString();
    item = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
}

public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView <?> parent)
{

}

protected void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public void buttonClicked_uloz(View button) 
{
    getData();

    if (predmet.length()<1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.invalid_nazov, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if (odosli.length()>0)
        {
            mDbHelper.updatePredmet(odosli, predmet, poloha, vyucujuci, hodina, obsah, item);
        } else {
            mDbHelper.createPredmet(username, predmet, obsah, poloha, vyucujuci, hodina, 1, item);
        }

        startActivity ();
    }
}

public void dbOperations ()
{
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseOp(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.fetchPredmet(odosli, 1);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    predmet = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_NAZOV));
    obsah = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_POZNAMKA));
    poloha = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_POLOHA));
    vyucujuci = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_VYUCUJUCI));
    hodina = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_HODINA));
    den = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_DLZKA));
}

public void getData ()
{
    EditText predmetInput = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.predmet));
    predmet = predmetInput.getText().toString();

    EditText obsahInput = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.obsah));
    obsah = obsahInput.getText().toString();

    EditText polohaInput = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.miesto));
    poloha = polohaInput.getText().toString();

    EditText vyucujuciInput = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.vyucujuci));
    vyucujuci = vyucujuciInput.getText().toString();

    hodina = fmtTime.format(time.getTime());
}

public void chooseTime (View v)
{
    if (odosli.length()>0)
    {
        new TimePickerDialog (PredmetPridajActivity.this, t, Integer.parseInt(hodina.substring(0,2)), Integer.parseInt(hodina.substring(3,5)),true).show();
    } else {
        new TimePickerDialog (PredmetPridajActivity.this, t, time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),time.get(Calendar.MINUTE),true).show();
    }
}

public void updateLabel()
{
    timeLabel.setText(fmtTime.format(time.getTime()));
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{
    public void onTimeSet (TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {                       
        time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        updateLabel();
    }
};

public void startActivity ()
{
    PredmetPridajActivity.this.finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to set default value to timerPicker? I don't understand the question

Comment: yes, i need set default value

Comment: watch my answer below

Comment: check please my answer below if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but this set current time like default

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:ss");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = sdf.parse("07:00");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);

        TimePicker picker = new TimePicker(getApplicationContext());
        picker.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));//your default hour
        picker.setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));// your default minute
```